# Moving raster layer using QGIS

Tags: coordinates

I'm a user of QGIS with a very precarious understanding of it, and I've been looking for a way to move a couple of raster layers that have no coordinates and have been given some default ones placed at the origin, to some specific coordinates I know. 
I've been trying to replicate some of the already existing solutions, but so far I've been out of luck.
What must I do to move this raster to some new coordinates?

Comment: So what was that you tried?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/5rr60v/transfer_coordinates_between_two_rasters/
This was one of the things, I didn't know where to begin, and later there were some errors for which I couldn't find a solution.
I tried creating another coordinate system without great certainty that it would work, but I couldn't bring it to fruition.
What I wouldn't like to use is the Georeferencer tool because it might warp my image a little. And I just want it to move from one point to another.
What can I do?